# Not able to get 'current-user-principal' for user from apple caldav server

Tags: caldav

I am trying to get current-user-principal from apple caldav server and getting 400 error from apple. It was working few days ago, not sure if anything is changed from apple's side as we didn't changed anything on our side.

Issue comes only with the request for fetching current-user-principal while other requests works fine. One strange thing I noticed that in other request if I don't pass credentials they gave 401 while this request gives 400 in this case. The url for request is https://p58-caldav.icloud.com and it gives 400 while opened in browser, while in past it asks for credentials while opening in browser. I am hitting request from postman by adding authorization header for credentials, also tried adding header depth:1. It doesn't work if I remove depth header also.

`URL : https://p58-caldav.icloud.com
Method : PROPFIND
Content-Type: text/xml
Request Body: <A:propfind xmlns:A='DAV:'><A:prop><A:current-user-principal/></A:prop></A:propfind>`

Expected result should have xml contaning current-user-principle.
Actual result is 400 error.

Comment: I'm in the same boat since yesterday, getting "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: @paul-2011 Is there any way to track it.

Comment: I submitted a ticket to Apple, not sure when they will shed some light into this. It amazes me how they can simply break something like this out of nothing.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 16 Sep 2019:** it seems that the **functionality of the endpoints has been restored so you will not need to apply the following solution**.

Here is a **temporary solutio**n in order to get by during the breakage. Please **read carefully and use at your own risk**.

I observed the same issue with `contacts.icloud.com` and `caldav.icloud.com` i.e. that now return a 400.

After some fiddling I found that if you add a single path after the `.com` those endpoints will still work (at least for retrieving the principal from where you can move on and use them as before without a problem). You can add for example `/co` in the end.

(But right now ANYTHING WILL WORK as long as it is a single path, even `/tangerine` `/apricot` or `/acorn` but let's use `/co`.)

So, the following endpoints will work right now:

- `https://contacts.icloud.com/co`
- `https://caldav.icloud.com/co`

(or for the particular endpoint used in the question by the OP try `https://p58-caldav.icloud.com/co` - I used for example with success `https://pXX-contacts.icloud.com/co` (replace pXX with your server number) although I suggest for such discoveries to use the more general endpoints `contacts` and `caldav`.)

**Warning**: those work around endpoints are not an in-place replacement for all the usages of the old endpoints. For example **building upon them like in the following example WILL NOT WORK**:
`https://caldav.icloud.com/co/{hidden-personal-id}/principal/`

**instead you can still use the old endpoints for the above case** (this will work):
`https://caldav.icloud.com/{hidden-personal-id}/principal/`

I am attaching screenshots of postman requests using them as they are working right now:

[image]

[image]

**Disclaimer**: the above endpoints work at the time of this post but since Apple has already broken the original endpoints there is no guarantee how long those will continue to work or that they will work as expected. I am giving you this solution in order to get by until Apple fixes the issue but use them at your own risk.

Comment: You are a genius!